# File permissions for root

Tags: files, root, access-control

So file permissions are divided into three parts, for example: `-rwxr--r-x`

I understand that the order is the following: owner, group, others

But, can `root` do anything with the file even if there is no access granted by user to 'others' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The kernel ignores permission modes when the user is the superuser, except for execute permission when trying to run a program. See

[Unix execute permission can be easily bypassed. Is it superfluous, or what's the intention behind it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/unix-execute-permission-can-be-easily-bypassed-is-it-superfluous-or-whats-the)

for more details on why the execute mode is still obeyed.